# sql sum specific counted values separately

Tags: sql, count, sum

I am trying to make a sql script that count the number of customers grouped by branch and it worked, but I want to divide the counted branches into region and sum every region, like this:

```
  numberofcustomer |  branch
-------------------+-----
                 3 | branch1-1
                 4 | branch1-2
                 7 | region1
                 3 | branch2-1
                 3 | branch2-2
                 2 | branch2-3
                 5 | region2
```

here is my code:

```
select Branch_name,
COUNT(customer.customerID) as numberofcustomer 
from customer inner join Branch
on customer.BranchID = Branch.BranchID 
group by Branch_name
ORDER By Branch_name
```

here is the result of my code:

```
  numberofcustomer | branch
-------------------+-----
                 3 | branch1-1
                 4 | branch1-2
                 3 | branch2-1
                 3 | branch2-2
                 2 | branch2-3
```

Comment: So you mean each branch name implicitly specifies which region it belongs to? That seems to be an "odd" design... I'd store the branch/region relation explicitly, in it's own column!

Comment: What happens when you reach `branch10-1`?

Comment: I agree with @jarlh. There should be some mapping between branch and region.Even I recommend you to create a table for relation between branch and region

Comment: @J19, there is a Branch table already, just needs a region_id column added to it.

Comment: @jarlh Even that is fine, without that its difficult to map between the branch and region.

Comment: What dbms are you using? String functions are different in every one of them

Comment: No dbms specified, so I hope OP will be satisfied by an ANSI SQL answer. (Will work with at least a few dbms products...)

Comment: Yea but the solution I had in mind is by using substring and it changes almost every dbms.. substring substr etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you create another table for regions
make a table for regions, and in the branches table that you already have add region Id as fk
make inner join between both tables as A for example and in your query, make the inner join between A and customers and group by region name